# Fetching data from mongodb through nodejs and express to a html page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

Basically, I want to show particular fields from "employees" collection into a html page. But even after searching a lot on web, I'm unable to do so.

Here is the route part from the server.js file:

```
app.get('/fetching', function(req, res){
    connection.fetcher(function(data)
        {
            res.render("testing.html",data);
        }
    );
});
```

Now this is the part from connection.js file:

```
var fetcher= function(callback) {
    var mongodb = require('mongodb');
    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/HippoFeedo';

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {

            console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
        }

        else {
            console.log('Connection established to', url);

            // Get the documents collection
            var collection = db.collection('employees');

            collection.find({},function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {

                    console.log(result);
                    callback(result);
                }

            });
        }
    });
```

Now, findOne is working fine and returning the value to `server.js` file perfectly. But I need to use "find", so how to send the complete array to the `server.js` through callback?

And moreover, I need to send that retrieved data from `server.js` to a HTML file called `testing.html` through rendering and display it through angular js. Please explain a simple way to do so.

EDIT:
I got to know how to work with "find", I just used "toArray" alongwith "find" in function. And now, I'm able to return the value to server.js through call back. But the other question is still unsolved: How do I pass those values to the html page?

Comment: you can look through jade for populating data in the UI side

Comment: I dont want to use jade or ejs.. Is that possible to do that using angularjs or jquery?

Answer (score 3):

Using ejs, you need to set the view engine:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Then get your data:

```
 app.get('/employees',(req , res) =>{
    db.collection('employees').find().toArray(function(err , i){
        if (err) return console.log(err)

        res.render('index.ejs',{employees: i})  
     })
 });
```

The .ejs file would be like this:

```
employees
  <ul class="employees">
  <% for(var i=0; i<employees.length; i++) {%>
    <li class="employees">
      <span><%= " Nome: " +employees[i].name+"."%></span>
      <span><%=" Address: " + employees[i].address%></span>
    </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Just a simple way using ejs. Hope it helps to clarify things.